# ListBox and Checkbox - XAML/C# - Windows 8 App

Tags: checkbox, listbox

I have a little problem with my Project. I have an `ListBox` with a `Checkbox` for each item. The `Checkbox` takes the Content from `ListBox`, but how do I connect the Selection of the Item and the IsChecked from the Checkbox?

My plan is that when you Check the Checkbox that the line with the Checked Checkbox will be deleted. How do I do that?

My XAML so far:

```
<ListBox x:Name="To_do_Liste"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="593" 
    Margin="0,85,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
    BorderBrush="#FDFFE818" Background="#FFFFE818"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" IsDoubleTapEnabled="True" 
    IsHoldingEnabled="True" IsRightTapEnabled="True"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ManipulationMode="All"
    FontFamily="SketchFlow Print" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="320"
    SelectionMode="Extended">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ListBoxItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox1" Foreground="Black"
          BorderBrush="#FF007FFF" Content="{Binding}" FontFamily="SketchFlow Print"
          FontSize="26" />
      </ListBoxItem>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: in WPF that would be `<CheckBox IsChecked={Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"/>`. I'm not sure if it works in WinRT, though. BTW remove the `ListBoxItem` from the `ItemTemplate` you don't need that.

Comment: This doesn't work because Win Metro Apps do not support AncestorType :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add selectionchange eventhandler to listbox and here you can check which checkbox is selected either using selectedindex of some other property of checkbox and now update your OBSERVABLECOLLECTION to with you listbox is binded.

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chkbx = sender as CheckBox;

    }
```

Comment: the Problem here ist that the Handler doesn't records when the Selection has changed.